# Azure Data Factory Inner Pipeline needs to list folder contents

Tags: azure, pipeline

I am trying to iterate over the folder contents within a called pipeline.
The folder name is being passed in as a parameter.

Either Get Meta Info is not able to extract the childItems or I am misunderstanding something very profound as I am running into "variable" is of type string not array type issues when running the foreach iterator.

Is what I am attempting even possible?

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: First Create a Dataset parameter for the folder name, you need to pass the parameter value to the Get Meta data activity. Then Give the childItems list output array to the ForEach. Please add the error image and at which you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and got the required result by using the dataset parameter.

First create a dataset parameter for the folder.

[image]

Now create parameter in child pipeline and parent pipeline.

**Child pipeline:**

[image]

**Parent Pipeline:**

[image]

Now give the parent parameter to child pipeline in Execute pipeline.

[image]

Now in the Meta data activity give the child pipeline parameter to the Dataset parameter.

[image]

Give the Child Items array to ForEach with expression `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`.

When running the parent pipeline, give the folder name to the parent parameter.

[image]

**Result in child pipeline:**

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have got the dataset properties figured out, but Child Items is not an option on my field list?

Comment: Hello, so here's an extra wrinkle that has just dawned upon me.
The folder structure is <container>/Directory/<unzipped_directory>/<textfile>

So my ChildItems are generating the following error.

Operation on target Get Metadata1 failed: Field 'childItems' failed with error: 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot navigate through the provided data source. Make sure the provided data source is a directory that can do navigation.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary

Comment: If you want the child Items inside your source folder, the path in the dataset should stop at the folder path itself like <container>/Directory/<unzipped_directory>/. Could you please check on that?

Comment: Hello, the <unzipped_directory> is a variable 

The structure I am trying to traverse is something like this:  

Container/Staging_Folder/<folder_derived_From_unzip_operation>/* Text files

The <folder_derived_from_unzip_operation> is a string variable. 

I am trying to traverse <folder_derived_from_unzip_operation> to build a list of files.

Comment: Yeah, I got your query. only give the path till your folder. don't give any * after that. Give the path as Container`/Staging_Folder/<folder_derived_From_unzip_operation/>` only.